# PHP getRandomURL generate random id

Tags: php

I want generate an random number behind my `.php` file.
But i dont see any results.

```
$login = "login.php";
```

**Heres the Code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");


header('Location:' . $login . $urlext);

$urlext = getRandomURL();

function getRandomURL() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['randomUrl'])) {
            $_SESSION['randomUrl'] =    '?assoc_handle=' .
                                                            substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 30) . 
                                                            '&openid_claim=' .
                                                            substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20) .
                                                            '&identifier_select=' .
                                                            substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20) .
                                                            '&pape_max=' .
                                                            substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 30);
            return $_SESSION['randomUrl'];
        } else {
            return $_SESSION['randomUrl'];
        }
    }


?>
```

The Page redirect to `/login.php` Location but dont generate an random number behind the file in the url. Any one an Idea? Or must i do it in an Session?

Comment: You're defining the `$urlext` variable after you're using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line in your php file:

`$urlext = getRandomURL();`

before

`header('Location:' . $login . $urlext);`